# Difference between `func<T: Type>` and `func<T>(..) where T: Type`?

Tags: swift, generics, code-formatting

When restricting the type of a generic argument, why is there 2 ways in Swift to do it?

1. `func<T: Type>`
2. `func<T>(..) where T: Type`

Is there a difference between the two or is this just legacy syntax left behind?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no difference, and I'm not aware of a convention.

Personally, prefer the first option, unless it makes the rest of the line have to line-break, in which case I use the second option instead.

Comment: I feel most Apple docs follows the 2nd option (see `Set`, `stride`, `zip`, etc) so probably there is some bias towards the 2nd option. But, personally, I also pick the 1st option in most cases too ;)

Comment: The second option allows you to constrain the associated types of the generic parameter too, which is a possible reason for the bias. @PauloMattos

Comment: @PauloMattos I think some of the reasoning might come down to the spelling of the generic types. Consider `func compareTwoThings<T>() where T: Comparable`. I consider protocols like `Equatable`, `Hashable`, `Comparable` to be kind of non-important "utility" protocols. They're not particular fundamental to the identity of the type, to the point where it's important to put the constraint right at the start...

Comment: @PauloMattos ... On the other hand, in `func makeWidget<F: WidgetFactory>()`, `F` is really important, and its identity is non-obvious. Putting `WidgetFactory` at the start makes sense for me, highlighting this is a critical aspect of the function API, rather than some "by the way" plumping like `Equatable`, `Hashable`, `Comparable`, which I'm more okay with tucking away further ahead/down in a `where` clause.

Comment: @Alexander Yep, those are good reasons too... but Apple documentation *definitely* has bias towards the 2nd option. Even the latest `SwiftUI` and `Combine` frameworks follow it almost exclusively as far as I can tell. I guess it doesn’t make much sense to tweak this style on a per API basis (for them at least), and better to pick one and stick with it ;)

Answer (score 1):

They are identical in function. The first version is there for legacy reasons, it's a holdover from Swift 1. The second version is newer in conception and considered "more proper" by Apple.